# Signal input with transform issue with transform

Tags: angular, angular-signals

I want to create a signal input with a transform attribute but the compiler throws an error:

```
foo = input<string, number>(0, {transform: numberAttribute });
```

Error:

```
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

What is the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is : try to not type your signals and let the inference do its job.

```
foo = input(0, {transform: numberAttribute });
```

[Playground demo for signal input type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzsAdmArjANHF6QBGAplAIIwxTAGZFwC%20cAZlBCHAOQACAhigOboANjygB6AMbQiHANwAoeWLFwAMkXiomJIigl0AJhGQwAznABWEAnACEtuIokjT5gGIRjCRXF-NPcAC8yGiYABQAzACUCn5wygB6APw%20fkyeAExBIRgwkThIlHym6VAgAFxwYQBuPELoRJV4hCRRQQB8VcCmAHI8PTV1DW1JcOgoBkRMqEQGcJW19URt9DHycYkp62meEdmouQB0UEQAjujAJwZhhVDFpRVViw1N%20MRQbYGdYd19A8-LOCjcaTaYoWbzOAAlZrDZiZKpXzpCAAFn2oRgxzOFyuNyKKBK0EezXe5Eo1Foq22vk2iPiKgA6gALHRwIgADzAQmAEmAmnM4P0rlEAE9HNT-BAAKzo3IAHhJJDgAB9cMIhO0wnghEIohLaRLkQA2WWYLHnS6zBVvEia2F%20A30IA)

---

## The long answer

The signal type definition is wrong. `InputSignal` has 2 generics : `ReadT` and `WriteT`.

`ReadT` is the type of your signal when you read it, `WriteT` is the type of the input.

So your signal input should be the other way around:

```
foo = input<number, string>(0, {transform: numberAttribute });
```

Not also that, using unknown is also possible:

```
foo = input<unknown, number>(300, { transform: numberAttribute });
```

---

Having to define both is actually due to a Typescript limitation, it doesn't support partial type inference so it's not possible to do this at the moment:

```
// will works when TS supports partial type inference
delay = input<number>(300, { transform: numberAttribute });
```